# Generalization of Cramer Rule

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I have a big system of equations with the form:
$$\left(
\begin{array}[cc]\\
A & B \\ C & D
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}[c]\\
X\\Y
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}[c]\\
T_1\\T_2
\end{array}
\right),$$
where $A,B,C$ and $D$ are square matrices and $X,Y,T_1,T_2$ are vectors.

Is there a Cramer's-like rule for solving that kind of system?

I'm interested in any theoretical explanation.

Comment: When all four are square matrices, you have one big square matrix. So why do you think it is  different from a one big $2n\times 2n$ equation system?

Comment: I solve it that way, but I can see a simple way to recover information from the original system in that way. I'm asking it because linear algebra deals with general vector spaces and Cramer rule is limited to Fields and I don't know why.